# Выбранный объект становится невидимым на время перетаскивания в picklist primeng

Tags: angular, primeng

использую primeng, а конкретно p-picklist. Пробую добавить его в p-dialog, все бы ничего, но при выборе строки и перетаскивании ее в target он становится невидимым. Если же использовать p-picklist не в p-dialog, то эффекты все присутствуют.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавлять код не вижу смысла, это базовый код [отсюда](https://primeng.org/picklist#style)
Буду признателен за помощь, спасибо

Comment: Если нет смысла добавлять то какого ответа хотите если [отсюда](https://primeng.org/picklist#style) всё работает нормально? смотрите стили свои, что-то где-то перекрывается